# Prevent Android from Redrawing a GridView

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a Grid View with around 256 button views. This view is contained in a layout that contains other buttons and widgets. Now when ever a press a button, the whole view get redrawn and also the GridView.

The Adapter is slightly heavy, and it causes a performance lag.

**Question:**
How do i prevent specifically the GridView from redrawing it self?

Comment: Its just a Relative Layout with a Grid view and other view in it. Pressing the buttons outside the GridView causes the GridView to redraw it self.

Comment: Without seeing your code, how should I give you reply. its not your layput issue, its the issue in your Java code.